# create symbolic link in directory with no write permission

Tags: linux, permissions, symbolic-link

I have a directory, which I do not have write access to. I want to create a symbolic link there, overwriting my file in that directory(which i own). however, I cant delete my file to place a symbolic link, and `ln -sf /path/to/target/ /path/to/dir/file` does not work, `permission denied`. so I need to put a symbolic link in the file. but how? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. note i deleted the GUI so it has to be terminal.

Comment: Unclear : How come you don't have write permission to a folder that you own? Please put some order in your description of the problem.

Comment: @harrymc no, a file that I own is in a directory of someone else(say, /)

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: why not? i have write access to the file, right?

Comment: But not to the directory.

Comment: so it's impossible? is it possible with a hard link to a file?

Comment: You can't create or modify *anything* in a directory to which you have no permissions. You might be able overwrite or delete the file that you own, but even that is not sure and depends on the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the file is a file permission action. Deleting the file is a directory permission action. Replacing a file is deleting a file and writing a new file, and both these actions are directory permissions.

Your permissions do not allow you to delete the file. In order to "replace" this file you need the correct permissions in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the directory with elevated permissions, or from a user or group that has write access to the directory, such as the owner or the owners group.

Even if you own the file in a directory, if someone did a chown or chmod and locked you out you can't modify the file there, modifying includes deleting a file you own, because its permissions propagate top down.

However can you list the contents of the directory because something is not making sense.

Consider this:

```
sudo su
mkdir test
cd test
touch test.txt
chown myuser:myuser test.txt
cd ..
chmod 644 test
```

Now when you logout into your shell, you are unable to even list the contents of the directory. But if you modify to 655 you can edit the file.  You need execute permissions on the directory to be able to access its contents, so that is 655.

Example under permission 644:

```
cd test
bash: cd: test: Permission denied

ls test
ls: cannot access 'test/test.txt': Permission denied
```

However if the directories permissions are 655 the file can be edited by the owning user account.

If this is the case and your user owns the file you can change the permisions yourself to something like 700 via

```
chmod 700 test.txt
```

however you won't be able to delete the file as you said without write permissions to the directory, so someone else will have to perform these changes for you.